# How to filter records when using ProjectTo with AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

Say following dto is given:

```
public record EntityDto : IMapFrom<Entity>
{
    ...

    public List<Child> Children { get; init; } = new();

    public void Mapping(Profile profile)
    {
        profile.CreateMap<Entity, EntityDto>()
            .ForMember(m => m.Children, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Children.Where(x => x.CreatedAt == childrenFilter ???)));
    }
}

public interface IMapFrom<T>
{
    void Mapping(Profile profile) => profile.CreateMap(typeof(T), GetType());
}
```

The entity will be projected to the dto using automapper:

```
var childrenFilter = DateTime.Now;

var entity = await _dbContext.Entity
    .ProjectTo<EntityDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

How can I include only some of the children in this setup, filtered with childrenFilter?

Comment: You need to write the filter in your `CreateMap` call.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Child list in your dto model, You should code like this:

```
var entity = await _dbContext.Entity
    .ProjectTo<EntityDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider,
        null,
        x => x.Children)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

If you need a field in Child model you can code like this:

```
var entity = await _dbContext.Entity
    .ProjectTo<EntityDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider,
        null,
        x => x.Children.Select(y => y.CreatedAt))
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

public record EntityDto : IMapFrom<Entity>
{
    ...

    public List<DateTime> CreatedAtList{ get; init; } = new();
}
```

Comment: I am trying to exclude children that match the given condition.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you can try to use "Where". "Select" is not for that.